# Likeliness of "A" being better than "B" using Poisson distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

## Background

I'm running an A-B test for two campaigns.

I got three step funnels set up for both campaigns.

So far B seems to be better than A, but how do I know when I have gathered enough measure points?

#### Funnel steps

In the data below, there are three steps. Step_1 is the number of users that reached our sign up page.

Step_2 is the number of users that filled in our sign up form

Step_3 is the number of users that confirmed their email address.

## Question

How can I calculate the likelihood that A is better than B, or vice versa?

Or more eloquently:

Given an "infinate amount of cases" where we have A:6 and B:8 observations in Step_3 and a conversion rate from Step_1 of A:12.5% and B:13.333...%. In how many of these cases does A end up with a higher conversion rate than B and vice versa?

```
    Step_1  Step_2  Step_3
A   144.0   18      6
B   135.0   18      8
```

#### Rationale

- Each user going through the funnel is unaffected by other users.
- Each user cannot reach the next step without going through the earlier.
- Each user will either stop at a step, or continue to the next. Giving only two options for each independent observation

This means a binomial distribution can be used to predict the likeliness of a user converting to the next step.

#### What I tried so far

So far I've tried using a poisson distribution

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import poisson
```

And using the `poisson.ppf` somehow I should be able to say "The likeliness of A being better than B is 5%, the likeliness of B being better than A is 25%."

Of course I can just plug in some values to the function and go "Hey, this looks great" but I feel like I need to call upon the vast knowledge of the Stacked Oracles of Stack Overflow to make sure I'm doing something statistically sound.

#### Why Poisson

In my humble understanding of distributions:

The poisson distribution is a lot like the binomial distribution ([`scipy.stats.binom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html)), but better suited for predictions involving few observations than it's `binom` big brother.

The poisson distribution is *a* binomial distribution, because it asserts two possible outcomes

The reason binomial distributions are what I want to use is because there are two outcomes in my simulated scenario, either the user proceeds down the funnel, or the user exits. This is the **bi** in **bi**nomial.

The poisson distribution is based on the assumption that two observations cannot affect each other. So wether or not user_1 makes it to step_3, step_2 or just to step_1, it does not matter for user_2. This is very much the case, they do not know of each others existence.

Comment: Looks like something more for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have a feeling that stats.stackexchange.com will give me an answer that I cannot understand due to it containing only mathematical formulas. I've asked questions there before. If I was as fluent in math as I am in python, I would just read the wikipedia page for poisson, which I did, which still left me unsure.

Comment: @firelynx Your predicament is perfectly understandable. I'm sure some hardliners are going to close-vote your question as strictly speaking it seems to be off-topic here. Though, maybe you will get an answer first :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what those steps and numbers mean, and how do you turn them into a metric to score "betternes"? Your rationale on why Poisson is the way to go would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically speaking Binomial is more precise in this case than Poisson. For example, using Poisson you'll get a positive probability of more than 18 of your 18 candidates making the conversion. Poisson owes its popularity to being easier to compute.

The result also depends on your prior knowledge. For example if both your outcomes look very high compared to typical conversion rates then all else being equal the difference you see is more significant.

Assuming no prior knowledge, i.e. assuming that every conversion rate between 0 and 1 is equally likely if you know nothing else, the probability of a given conversion rate *r* once you take into account your observation of 6 out of 18 possible conversions is given by the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), in this case Beta(*r*; 6+1, 18-6+1)

Technically speaking this is not a probability but a *likelihood*. The difference is the following: a probablity describes how often you will observe different outcomes if you compare "parallel universes" that are identical, even though reputable statisticians probably wouldn't use that terminology. A likelihood is the other way round: given a fixed outcome comparing *different* universes how often will you observe a particular kind of universe. (To be even more technical, this description is only fully correct if as we did a "flat prior" is assumed.) In your case there are two kinds of universe, one where A is better than B and one where B is better than A.

The probability of B being better than A is then

integral_0^1 dr Beta_cdf(r; 6+1, 18-6+1) x Beta_pdf(r; 8+1, 18-8+1)

You can use `scipy.stats.beta` and `scipy.integrate.quad` to calculate that and you'll get a 0.746 probability of B being better than A:

```
quad(lambda r: beta(7, 13).cdf(r) * beta(9,11).pdf(r), 0, 1)
# (0.7461608994979401, 1.3388378385104094e-08)
```

To conclude, by this measure the evidence for B being better than A is not very strong.

**UPDATE:**

The two step case can be solved conceptually similarly, but is a bit more challenging to compute.

We have two steps 135 / 144 -> 18 -> 8 / 6. Given these numbers how are the conversion rates for A and B and step 1 and step 2 distributed? Ultimately we are interested in the product of step 1 and step 2 for A and for B. Since I couldn't get scipy to solve the integrals in reasonable time I fell back to a Monte Carlo scheme. Just draw the conversion rates with appropriate probabilites N=10^7 times and count how often B is better than A:

```
(beta(9,11).rvs(N)*beta(19,118).rvs(N) > beta(7,13).rvs(N)*beta(19,127).rvs(N)).mean()
```

The result is very similar to the single step one: 0.742 in favour of B. Again, not very strong evidence.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. "0.746 probability" Means in 3 out of 4 cases?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The mathematical model is there is a large set of parallel universes or if that's to scifi for your liking conceivable scenarios. By only a subset of those is compatible with your observations. And of this subset about 3 quarters include a B that is better than A and one quarter an A that is better than B.

Comment: Superb! Please put that into your answer too

Comment: Added a paragraph.